# Can full device encryption be achieved on a self-launching device without manual input (passphrase)?

Tags: linux, encryption

Is it theoretically possible to have a secure setup where an encrypted device decrypts itself without manual input?

Keyfiles (as opposed to passphrases) are obviously a solution but if the keyfile is accessible to the decrypting system (boot partition) then it will also be readable to anyone reading the boot partition.

Perhaps there are some clever techniques of how to achieve this. One idea which comes to mind is having a closed-sourced initiating partition which has the (initial) encryption keys.

I'm asking this question on an abstract level so not to limit the possibilities of good responses. In practice, my question applies to an Arch-Linux device. I can use block-device encryption and store the keyfile in the boot partition and even encrypt the boot partition but ultimately somewhere down the chain the key needs to be exposed in a non-encrypted manner.

Comment: Yes, you need a TPM.

Comment: Store the key on another machine, and grab it from network in booting process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

Without manual interaction, the key must be accessible by the device automatically.
As it is just a device, you can "manually" reproduce/execute its actions to read the key.

As obscurity is not a means of security, having a "closed-source" resource is also not secure.
For instance, it may be very expensive to read a key stored on a smartcard - but you can just query the smartcard as the device does.